# setTicker not showing up text

Tags: android, android-notifications

My notification doesn't show up the text on the status bar, but the sound and other options work perfectly. I'm on Android L, is this some kind of bug?

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(LocalService.this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setTicker("Ticker Text")
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationContent)
                .setSound(ringtoneUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(LocalService.this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(LocalService.this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: And what happens if you use `Notification.Builder` instead of `NotificationCompat.Builder`?

Comment: @SimonMarquis Same result.

Comment: It's a preview release anyway. Maybe you could take a look at https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/list, or even directly on the source code ;)

Comment: @SimonMarquis It's a bug and is already reported, I found it on the list, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that has been reported already.

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=60&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not a bug, according to Google [API document about Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#tickerText)

> Text that summarizes this notification for accessibility services. As of the L release, this text is no longer shown on screen, but it is still useful to accessibility services (where it serves as an audible announcement of the notification's appearance).

So after Android L, we cannot get tickerText show on the screen. For more information you can check Android Police [article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/14/lollipop-feature-spotlight-the-status-bar-notification-ticker-is-gone-and-thats-kind-of-dumb/).

Comment: use `notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);` to see in the status bar